# Matlab set all return values at once

Tags: matlab

I have a function taking and returning a list of variables `[a,b,c]` etc. Because of the layout of the program I've assigned these to a variable as `p=[a,b,c]` and then iterated through them to set them (because matlab has no `for i in []` statement that I can find).

I thus have all the return values set in a list/array `p`, to return. How do I set them all at once? I tried `[a,b,c]=p` but that doesn't work; I could manually set them as `a=p(1),b=p(2)` etc but that seems rather inelegant.

Comment: `[a,b,c]=deal(p)`. There's a duplicate out there probably on this.

Comment: Use `deal` or use `repmat` on a cell array version of `p` and then use the accepted answer to the linked dup question.

Comment: Many thanks; sorry didn't spot the duplicate. That works perfectly.